# How to Find out when your Office 365 subscription expires with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The Power Shell  cmdlet Get-MsolSubscription has a NextLifecycleDate field which gives me the expiry data of my Office 365  subscription. Microsoft Graph Get subscribedSku does not appear to include this info.

Is there a Graph API to get the the expiry data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the endpoints in Graph return a `NextLifecycleDate` property. The `Get-MsolSubscription` is most likely retrieving this data from another source (i.e. the O365 cmdlets may not always be using the Graph behind the scenes).

Comment: Seems like an important piece of data to not include.

Comment: The Microsoft Graph SubscribedSKU has a WarningUnits property that shows licenses that have not been renewed and will expire within 30 days. That's part way there, just can't say when the licence will expire.

Comment: @tom.kanary microsoft actively depreciate useful data.